# ffmpeg delay in appearing the image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, latency, delay

I am using ffmpeg with 264nvenc to transcode streaming channels. the result is very good the channels look great and are very stable, the problem is that when you open the channel, the sound is heard at the beginning, but the image takes 5-7 seconds to appear, they have no synchronization problem, just that the image takes that time to appear.

the entry is in http mpgts and ffmpeg converts it to UDP 224.0.0.1:9000

can you please help me?

There is some configuration file that can be modified to solve it, since there are many links and it cannot be one to one.

I don't consume too much hardware resources, below 20% -30%
i have 32gb ram, 4 nvida tesla k10, intel xeon e5

---

I have erased everything, I have installed windows 10 and ffmpeg, I still have the same problem, the image takes 5-7 seconds to appear after the sound, but it has no synchronization problem.

this is the code

ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -deint 1 -y -i http://192.168.5.100:9090/ch4?u=trews:p=23423423543553 -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1500k -bufsize 1000k  -gpu 1 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -map 0 -sn -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:9000?pkt_size=1316

I don't know what else to try, please help me
Thank you

Comment: I've tried with 1 single channel and it's the same

Comment: I googled my own answer and it looks like your question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658873/how-to-minimize-the-delay-in-a-live-streaming-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -deint 1 -y -i http://192.168.5.100:9090/ch4?u=trews:p=23423423543553 -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1500k -bufsize 1000k -gpu 1 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -map 0 -sn -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:9000?pkt_size=1316